# How can I set configuration values in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, module, configuration

Previously (in Magento 1, that is) we created a module called Setup which contained setting for the site. The upgrade scripts looks something like this:

```
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
$installer->setConfigData("fastsimpleimport/general/partial_indexing", 1);
$installer->setConfigData("fastsimpleimport/product/disable_preprocess_images", 1);
$installer->setConfigData('general/country/default', 'GB');
$installer->setConfigData('general/locale/firstday', 1); 
$installer->setConfigData('general/locale/timezone', 'Europe/London');
$installer->setConfigData('general/store_information/merchant_country', 'GB');
$installer->setConfigData('design/header/welcome', 'Enter your value');
$installer->setConfigData('design/head/title_suffix', 'Enter your value');
$installer->setConfigData('currency/options/base', 'GBP');
$installer->setConfigData('currency/options/default', 'GBP');
// ...
```

I can't figure out how to do the above in M2.

In other words: How do I go about setting config data in M2?

Comment: why do you need these in the DB? Can't you just add it in the `config.xml` file?

Comment: That's just the way things are done. It seems to be the common approach handling settings in module extensions (at least in M1). Also they need to be handled on a version basis so they can be migrated when our module is upgraded.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface 
{
    public function __construct(
        LoggerInterface $loggerInterface,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ConfigResource\ConfigInterface  $resourceConfig)
    {
        $this->logger = $loggerInterface;
        $this->resourceConfig = $resourceConfig;
    }        

    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();

        $this->resourceConfig->saveConfig(
            'a/b/c', 
            'value', 
            \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface::SCOPE_TYPE_DEFAULT, 
            \Magento\Store\Model\Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID
        );

        $setup->endSetup();
    }   
}
```

Comment: I think it may also work (and be cleaner) to use interface from DI in the constructor for the $resourceConfig object. Like this: `\Magento\Framework\App\Config\ConfigResource\ConfigInterface $resourceConfig`

Comment: Hey Martin, can you share some more of your module? I´m struggling in what namespace etc i need to use?!

Comment: why did you add logger also? just a habit or?

Comment: Definitely not required to add the logger as the `InstallDataInterface` does not provide a method signature for the constructor, so you are free to use any parameters you like there. As for the module itself: There is nothing else required besides the obligatory `registration.php` for this script to run during setup after the module has been enabled.

Answer (score 7):

The following interface can be used `\Magento\Framework\App\Config\Storage\WriterInterface`, it has 2 methods:

- `save($path, $value, $scope = ScopeConfigInterface::SCOPE_TYPE_DEFAULT, $scopeId = 0)`
- `delete($path, $scope = ScopeConfigInterface::SCOPE_TYPE_DEFAULT, $scopeId = 0)`

It is more high-level compared to `\Magento\Config\Model\ResourceModel\Config`, and should be used from client code.