# Magento 2 Setup/update System/store Configuration values through setup script

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.3

How I should 'Setup/update System/store Configuration values through setup script'? Trying with Setup/Patch/Data script using something like

//app/code/Namespace/Module/Setup/Patch/Data/SetupConfigData.php

```
namespace Namespace\Module\Setup\Patch\Data;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\DataPatchInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\MutableScopeConfigInterface;

class SetupConfigData implements DataPatchInterface
{

const XML_PATH_STORE_NAME = 'general/store_information/name';

const XML_PATH_STORE_PHONE = 'general/store_information/phone';

const XML_PATH_ADMIN_ACCOUNT_SHARING = 'admin/security/admin_account_sharing';

const XML_PATH_ADMIN_URL_SECRET_KEY = 'admin/security/use_form_key';

const SCOPE_STORE = 'store';

/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Config\MutableScopeConfigInterface
 */
private $mutableScopeConfig;

/**
 * @var ModuleDataSetupInterface
 */
private $moduleDataSetup;

public function __construct(
    ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup,
    MutableScopeConfigInterface $mutableScopeConfig
)
{

    $this->moduleDataSetup = $moduleDataSetup;
    $this->mutableScopeConfig = $mutableScopeConfig;
}

public function apply()
{
    $this->moduleDataSetup->startSetup();
    $this->mutableScopeConfig->setValue(self::XML_PATH_STORE_NAME, "Title", self::SCOPE_STORE);
    $this->mutableScopeConfig->setValue(self::XML_PATH_STORE_PHONE, "Default contact", self::SCOPE_STORE);
    $this->mutableScopeConfig->setValue(self::XML_PATH_ADMIN_ACCOUNT_SHARING, 0, self::SCOPE_STORE);
    $this->mutableScopeConfig->setValue(self::XML_PATH_ADMIN_URL_SECRET_KEY, 0, self::SCOPE_STORE);
    $this->moduleDataSetup->endSetup();
}

public function getAliases()
{
    return [];
}

public static function getDependencies()
{
    return [];
}
}
```

Environment: `Magento 2.3.3` and nothing changed after running `setup:upgrade`, am not sure what am I missing.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at answers to questions like this

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/104379/70343

This seems to work:

```
class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface 
{
    public function __construct(
        LoggerInterface $loggerInterface,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ConfigResource\ConfigInterface  $resourceConfig)
    {
        $this->logger = $loggerInterface;
        $this->resourceConfig = $resourceConfig;
    }        

    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();

        $this->resourceConfig->saveConfig(
            'a/b/c', 
            'value', 
            \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface::SCOPE_TYPE_DEFAULT, 
            \Magento\Store\Model\Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID
        );

        $setup->endSetup();
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for System Config, it is better to use the `config.xml`. 
Maybe you have already applied this change to Database this information you can find with the following Query. A Data Patch applies only one time on a System.

```
Select * FROM patch_list WHERE patch_name
LIKE '%SetupConfigData%'
```

best regards,

Lars

Comment: the fields that I want to update are Magento core system config settings, using config.xml didnt worked so tried Patch/Data and that is not working as expected